# Java: Parsing for empty spaces using Pattern and Matcher

Tags: java, regex

I have a form with an edit box for entering valid email-address. I dont want the user to enter spaces in the email id edit box. As soon a text is entered i call two funcs

```
isEmailValid(String s) || isLoginValid(String s)
isEmailValid(String s){
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[\\.\\w-]*(@[\\.\\w-]*)?$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    return matcher.matches();
}

isLoginValid(String s){
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\w+$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```

This pattern works fine when the user enters the email-id for the first time. But as soon as the user deletes a char and enters a space, this logic breaks. I dont want user to enter spaces as email-id.

Can any help point out where i am going wrong?

Comment: SpunkerBaba:Try to print out the outputs of the 2 functions.Also I think you should use isEmailValid(String s) && isLoginValid(String s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but is it possible that it is matching the e-mails because it is matching your string because most everything is zero or more times? Followed by something that can happen zero or more times. Maybe try something like:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[\\w]+[\\.\\w-]*(@[\\w-]+\\.[\\w-]+)?$");
```

I'm not sure if this will help.
Also, You probably want both to have to be valid, but maybe not. It's worth considering if you wanted:

```
isEmailValid(String s) && isLoginValid(String s)
```

instead of:

```
isEmailValid(String s) || isLoginValid(String s)
```

but it's also possible (and potentially logical) that you meant what you wrote. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Solves my problem, but introduces a new one. As soon as i enter "@" Matcher returns false and my purpose fails.

Comment: Solved. isEmailValid(String s) || isLoginValid(String s) along with your suggested Pattern works like charm. Your answer is accepted :)

Comment: @SpunkerBaba Good deal! Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

regexp are not universal matchers. the easiest way to solve your task is to make additional check for empty string:

```
 if (org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isBlank(email)) {
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: This would probably be considerably easier. I dare say try this before my answer.

Comment: As per `StringUtils.isBlank()` javadoc: `Checks if a String is whitespace, empty ("") or null.`. Which is essentially same as checking `if((email == null) || (email.trim().length() == 0))`. Also instead of `if (org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isBlank(email))  return false; }` you can write it as `return !org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isBlank(email);`